# Run project issue (always asks login and passwords)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, keychain

I chached my keychain (deleted some keys, because I had too many unnecessary keys and certificates in keychain).

And now, when I run any project, I'm asked to enter my system login and password.

[image]

When I enter, I'm not asked to save password in keychain. The app is starting successfully, but when I try to run project one more time, the loggin window appears anyway.

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that your certificate on Keychain was under "System", on the left hand panel, which is always locked, requiring my password to unlock!

Then You moved it to "login", which is always unlocked, and now everything works perfectly. The annoyance of xCode asking for the password is gone.

So my suggestion is that please create new new keychain and insert all certificate which uses into Development.

this may solve your problem 100%.

Comment: pls create admin keychain right click -> unlock keychain and make as a defaulf

Comment: I just deleted all keys and certificates from all keychains, and double clicked the certificate, so it appeared both in System and Login keychain. But after first application rus, xcode asked me to always get information from keychain

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your Developer certificate on Keychain is under "System", which is always locked, requiring your password to unlock.

You have to move it to "login", which is always unlocked, and then everything will work perfectly. Asking username and password again and again will be gone.